# measure the overall similarity between two vectors

Tags: correlation, count-data, cosine-similarity

I have two paired vectors which report the number of times each object was found in the two experiments (the count value could be 0 or greater (e.g. 5,10,1000, etc)). I want to compare them and get a score that indicates how similar they are. I thought about using the spearman correlation/cosine angle.

Is there a better score I could use?

Comment: There are a bunch of options: mean squared deviation, mean absolute deviation, median squared deviation, median absolute deviation, Spearman correlation, Pearson correlation, and dot product angle all come to mind. Which you would prefer will depend on what you mean by "better". What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I just want to show that they are very similar. I did two experiments and I would like to show that I can get (more or less) the same results

Comment: You can use cosine similarly / Jaccard distance

Comment: Cosine similarity is the same as dot product angle. An issue that I see with this (along with the correlation-based methods) is that one can be a multiple of the other and return perfect similarity. You might be fine with this (I don't know your experiment), but it might be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a score that can work better than correlation/cosine similarity with the issue reported by you? thanks!

Comment: My first comment listed four: something involving the deviations between components.